# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:oracle driver not found

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jpa, gradle

I am using `SPRING BOOT ORACLE JPA` with `GRADLE` a simple project but while running I am getting:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method
>   'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class:
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

My application.properties are:

```
server.port=8082 # create n drop tables, loads import.sql 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop 
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//138.69.14.63:1521/drbadev 
spring.datasource.username=$$$$$$$$$$ spring.datasource.password=$$$$$$ 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: my application.properties is

Comment: server.port=8082


# create n drop tables, loads import.sql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//138.69.14.63:1521/drbadev
spring.datasource.username=$$$$$$$$$$
spring.datasource.password=$$$$$$
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Comment: Can you add the POM file to the question please?